# Confusion - significance level and confidence interval

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

So the solution says:[image]

[image]

I actually understood all the likelihood ratio test and the test statistic for the goodness of fit. The only thing I did not quite understand is that, how do you calculate the upper-$a$ quantitle at significant level $a=5$%?

I thought the significant level at $5$% would be the same as the $95$%  confidence interval. But the $95$% confidence interval will be:

[image] 
then, the upper bound for the 95% CI:

$0.7684+1.96*0.00047^{0.5}= 0.810891787$

which is nowhere near $5.99$. So where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not try to follow your argument at the end about a confidence
interval. It is not clear for what parameter you are finding a CI, and
under what assumptions. Or whether you intend a one- or two-sided CI.

Following your text, the quantity

$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^4 \frac{(O_i - E_i)^2}{E_i}$$

is approximately distributed as $\textsf{Chisq}(\nu=2).$
So the critical value for a test at the 5% level cuts 5% from the
upper tail of $\textsf{Chisq}(\nu=2).$ (There are conditions for
this approximation, which you should check in your text.)

According to R statistical software, and also printed tables of
the chi-squared distribution, this value is 5.99, as stated.

```
qchisq(.95, 2)
## 5.991465
```

In the plot of the density function below, the area under the curve to
the right of the dotted red vertical line is 5%. Large values of $Q$
correspond to *poor* fit. This is a right-tailed test. A value of $Q = 0$ would indicate perfect
fit of observed counts to expected counts.

[image]

[Note: If you have a specific question about your 'derivation' of a CI, please
clarify your goals and assumptions.]